# php FastCGI process killing server

Tags: php, php-fpm

I have this little problem on my server. Few times a week my server goes down for few minutes (2-3). All i could see was that every time one of the `php-fpm` processes is on 100% in `top`.
As well as that our drive has a little write spike (by little i mean 4M throughput on 3disk SSD array.)

Server is running on NGINX + FPM, LEMP server. It has 24Cores, 48G RAM and 3xSSD's RAID5 array.

I have checked the error logs and other logs too, and there does not seem anything I could cache on ...
It's been happening for over a week now, and I am starting to get worried.

Anyone have had any similar problems ? or could point me to some direction ? That would be lovely. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable PHP-FPM's slow log.  This would dump a stack trace of your application whenever it runs longer then X seconds (I believe this defaults to 10).

It's impossible for anyone to tell you what is actually causing the issue with just the information given so far.  I can tell you it's almost certain some code in the application you are running.

Comment: cheers, I ll try doing that.

Comment: awesome advice, works like a charm, much <3